# Selecting From Dynamic Attribute ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, select, dynamic

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC3 project which has multi-language support. I hold all the words in database and select from it according to a Session value. At present I get the value as the following:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string lang = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
        if (lang == "Tr" || lang == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Admin = db.Words.Find(10).Tr;
        }
        else if(lang == "En") 
        {
            ViewBag.Admin = db.Words.Find(10).En;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The present type of Word:

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Tr { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
}
```

However, the number of languages will raise, and with the present method I need to add these by hand. What I want is getting the word's "Session" language form dynamically such as (in pseudo):

```
ViewBag.Admin = db.Words.Find(10)."Session[Language]";
```

I know it should be easy but couldn't find the appropriate keywords to find this. Any idea how can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: I just need a way to execute an SQL String like the following:

```
String lang = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
ViewBag.MyWord = ExecuteSQL.("SELECT " + lang + " FROM Words WHERE ID = " + 10 + " ");
```

**EDIT 2**: I tried the following lines:

```
ViewBag.Admin = db.Words.SqlQuery("SELECT" + 
                (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] + 
                "FROM Words WHERE ID=10");
```

However, the output for this is the query itself on the screen. (SELECT Tr FROM Words WHERE ID=10)

Comment: What ORM are you using? EF?

Comment: Yes, I use EntityFramework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF as your ORM you could do something like this:

```
int wordId = 10;
string lang = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
var query = "SELECT " + lang + " FROM Words WHERE ID = {0}";
var word = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, wordId).FirstOrDefault();
```

See here for more info on raw sql queries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

**NOTE:** The above could be open to sql injection, probably best to test that it's a 2 character language code before sending the sql request to the server.

Comment: Thanks, security against sql injection isn't an issue for me on this project. However, on 4th line of your example code, I got the error:

"The non-generic method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RexamOneriSistemi.Models.Word>.SqlQuery(string, params object[])' cannot be used with type arguments xxx/HomeController"

Comment: Looks like you're calling `context.Words.SqlQuery<string>()` and not `context.Database.SqlQuery<string>()`. You might also need to cast the int to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by reflection. Just get the property by the language-key.

Here is some code:

```
 Word word = ...
 string lang = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
 PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Word).GetProperty(lang);
 return pi.GetValue(word, null);
```

I did not at exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression/delegate.

Write a methode returning the expression depending on `Session["Language"]`.

```
private string GetLanguageStringByKey(int key){
    return GetFuncByLanguage()(db.Words.Find(key));
}

private Func<Word,string> GetFuncByLanguage(){

    string lang = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
    Func<Word, string> func;
    switch(lang){
         case "En":{
            func = w => w.En;
            break;
         }
         default:{
            func = w => w.Tr;
            break;
         }
    }
    return func;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Admin = GetLanguageStringByKey(10);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @IsmetAlkan I expected that 10 is a kind of key.

Comment: This is just using switch instead of if's.